# which stochastic process can generate $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$ distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

$$\frac{1}{\cosh(x)} = \frac{2}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$

is similar to scaled normal distribution $e^{-x^2}$ in general shape. We know that central limit theorem say that the summation of independent identical random variables will lead to a distribution of the scaled $e^{-x^2}$.

Question: which type stochastic process or random walks can led to a distribution of $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$ ?

Comment: It is not at all similar: it goes to $+\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.  Perhaps you mean $1/\cosh(x)$?

Comment: Assuming you mean $1/\cosh(x)$, you can cook up something with that as its stationary distribution painlessly enough using MCMC methodology, but I can't think of a way it appears "naturally". Maybe think of it as a random sign times an exponential variate, and then exponential variates appear naturally in continuous time memoryless processes.

Comment: also what about the minus sign inside the $\cosh$ since it is an even function ?

Comment: @RobertIsrael , thank you for the comments. I mean $\frac{1}{cosh(x)}$

Comment: @Ian, what do you mean " exponential variates appear naturally in continuous time memoryless processes " ?

Comment: The holding times in time-homogeneous continuous time Markov chains are exponentially distributed. But I was mixed up, 1/cosh is not the same as $e^{-|x|}$.

Comment: Thank you.  $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$                 is very similar to $e^{-|x|}$.